# How do I click image elements and words on a webpage in selenium nodejs?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm coding in NodeJS and I'm trying to use the by.css variable to click on images and words on my website in selenium. I'm having trouble with this because I don't understand what to type into the by.css variable in order to make this work.

My code so far is:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

// Example function to automate browser interactions
async function automateBrowser() {
    // Create a new instance of the browser
    const driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    try {
        // Navigate to the website
        await driver.get('https://vitech-104517.square.site/');

        // Find and click an element (replace 'your-element-selector' with the actual selector)
        const element = await driver.findElement(By.css('your-element-selector'));
        await element.click();

        // Add more interactions as needed
    
        // Example: Wait for an element to appear (replace 'your-target-element-selector')
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('your-target-element-selector')), 5000);

        // Example: Click another element
        const anotherElement = await driver.findElement(By.css('your-another-element-selector'));
        await anotherElement.click();

        // Add more interactions as needed

    } finally {
        // Close the browser when done
        console.log("hello")
    }
}

// Call the function to start the automation
automateBrowser();
```

I want to input my code into your-element-selector and click on elements on the website. How do I get the css element in order to do this?